# Is really better to use NResponder than native events on Flash plataform?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nresponder

I work in a company that we mantain a 3 year old-software that were tottally written using native events(very poorly) and we are planning to refactor it entirely.

My colleague stands in a way that he is totally in favour of implementing [NResponder](http://code.google.com/p/nineveh-responder/wiki/DispatchAdvanced) but i'm a bit sceptic about this "amazing super-duper all-problems solution" and don't think that it's really worth it since:

1. Someday the NResponder project could be abandoned
2. In a near future AVM can be improved and native events can become amazingly
   faster
3. New teammates won't suffer from the cost of learning the
   whole new way of manipulating events
4. NResponder works in a way
   that is less "ruled" than native events in case of dispatching
   custom events with specific parameters, NResponder sends anything as
   parameters and you dont have any way to create business roles for
   this.

So it's really worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a big problem to NResponder be abandoned, you could keep using some version 'till the end of time. The problem is: if you discover any major bug in NResponder, you'll be forced to fix by yourself until the project owners fix it, if they fix it.

In your place I'd make efforts into using native events (even if you wrap them into some custom classes to ease your refactoring, **if you can keep those classes loosely coupled**)  because the other points you've mentioned (learning curve and AVM improvements) are far more important.

Native events are more reliable.